# list created from query, how to check against the results (Python)?

Tags: python

I run the query below:

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query3 = ("SELECT eventCode FROM eventinfo WHERE eventType = 1 AND isSaved = 1")
    cur.execute(query3)
    for row3 in cur:
        message_list.append(row3)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

the list message_list populates properly and when printed looks like `[('ABC',), ('BCA',), ('CBA',)]`

I would like to run something like this below, but it never matches, can someone tell me why?

```
if 'ABC' in message_list:
    do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a list of strings, you have a list of 1-tuples. Either:

1. Switch to `if ('ABC',) in message_list:` (i.e. check for the tuple in the list); or
2. Switch to `message_list.append(row3[0])` (i.e. make the list contain strings).

Comment: I used step 2, it makes more sense to me to have the result the string I am actually looking for, and it is now working, as I expected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the tuple `('ABC',)`, instead of `'ABC'`:

```
>>> 'ABC' in [('ABC',), ('BCA',), ('CBA',)]
False
>>> ('ABC',) in [('ABC',), ('BCA',), ('CBA',)]
True
```

BTW, if your purpose is to check whether the record with `ABC` event code is there, you'd better use `WHERE` SQL clause.

Comment: I have tried your answer, but it still is not returning true.